# How to detect if tmux is attached to a session in bash?

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a `.sh` file which create a new session for tmux and add some windows, the file should be used only when no session exist. For instance:

```
tmux new-session -A -s `ax` -n ui -d
# add windows and other magic here...
```

I want prevent creating a session with the same name and recreating the windows in case the `.sh` file is accidentally re executed and the session is running.

Basically what I need is:

> If a tmux session ax does not exist with that session name, create that session. If
>   I am not attached to a tmux session, attach to that session.

I would like to know how to detect if a tmux session exist and if tmux is attached to it, in this example `ax` is running and preventing the execution of the `.sh` script or if the session does not exit I want to re-execute the `.sh` script.

Currently I was thinking to use:

`tmux ls | grep attached`

I would like to know if you know a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand what you mean. I'm interpreting it as

> if a tmux session does not exist with that session name, create it. If I am not attached to a tmux session, attach to that session name.

If this is wrong, please comment.

I have similar functionality in my scripts. All I do is

```
tmuxstart() {
    tmux ls | grep "sess" && { tmux a -t sess; return 0; }
    #rest of tmux script to create session named "sess"
    tmux a -t sess
}
```

If the session named "sess" exists, then I execute the next 2 grouped commands on the line (attach to it and exit the function).

Note that I do *not* have to check if I'm already attached to the function. tmux does this automatically. If you try to attach to a tmux session while in a session, it will respond

```
sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force
```

and not recursively attach. Tmux is smart enough to keep us from shooting ourselves in the foot.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$TMUX` to detect if already attached, my code is:

```
if [ ! "$TMUX" ]; then
        tmux attach -t main || tmux new -s main
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my ~/.bashrc so if no sessions exist, start them & detach from all but ipfs session.

```
IPFS_SESSION=$(tmux attach-session -t ipfs 2>&1)
if [ "$IPFS_SESSION" == "sessions should be nested *" ]; then
  unset TMUX
else
  if ! tmux has-session -t sql;  then tmux new-session -d -s sql;  fi
  if ! tmux has-session -t tmp;  then tmux new-session -d -s tmp;  fi
  if ! tmux has-session -t ytdl; then tmux new-session -d -s ytdl; fi
  if ! tmux has-session -t ipfs; then tmux new-session -s ipfs; fi
fi
```